# JabRef 3.4 starts but unuseable on Mac

Tags: jabref

I have successfully installed Jabref 3.4 and it starts, but all I get is a menu including Services, which does not expand, and quit that won't end the program (must force quit).

I am running OSX 10.11.5.

Any ideas to get it working will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check that the file you downloaded is complete. Maybe try  a different source like GitHub.

Comment: This is likely off-topic for us: JabRef as a BibTeX editor is in our scope, but more general 'not working' stuff is better handled elsewhere.

Comment: If you installed MacTeX-2016 try using BibDesk for now. It can be found in /Applications/TeX.

Answer (score 2):

The [current OS X build of JabRef 3.4](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/1481) is broken. The reason for this is rather minor, a corrupted icon, but it is enough to break the release.

This bug has already been fixed in the current development version and there should be a new 3.4.1 release in the next weeks. For now, you can either [download a development build](http://builds.jabref.org/master/) or stick with JabRef 3.3 until the next release.